# mixing pointers to signed and unsigned in C

Tags: pointers, c99

Suppose I have an integer variable with non-negative value and two pointers to it - one signed and one unsigned pointer. As far as I can tell from the standard, this is fine.

> 6.5
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types: (*) — a type
> compatible with the effective type of the object, — a qualified
> version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object, —
> a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
> effective type of the object, — a type that is the signed or unsigned
> type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the
> object, — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the
> aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a
> member of a subaggregate or contained union), or — a character type.
>
> (*) The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

Are the two pointers guaranteed by the standard to have the same layout in memory? In particular, is the last line true?

```
unsigned value = 3;
int *i = (int *)&value;
unsigned *u = &value;

memcmp(&i, &u, sizeof(u)) == 0;
```

One case where this can matter is a variadic function that expects an `int *` but is passed an `unsigned *`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends!

It matters what the variadic function is doing with the pointer.
E. g. if it is copying the values from one memory place to another, it is ok.
Even with bitwise and/or/not operators.

E. g. above `memcmp(...) == 0` is ok.

But if the value is taken to calculate and some of the values are different if interpreted between signed and unsigned, then of course the outcome is different.
But if above  `memcmp(...) < 0` could fail, if such values would be found at u and i for the length of u.

PS: The code lines before `memcmp` in your example are such, that i and u will contains the same address, therefore the same bitwise representation of this address, and therefore `memcmp(i, u, sizeof(u)) == 0` will always return true!

PS2: But you use `memcmp(&i, &u, sizeof(u)) == 0` what are the pointers to the variables i and u - and the function memcmp compares the values (binary) (so the variables i and u content) that are equal.
So it will return true.

After comment:

My answer fits even if your first line "Suppose I have an integer variable with non-negative value and" is not true. `memcmp` compares a number of bytes in memory (bitwise, binary), no matter if the bytes of both memory areas are representing chars, strings, (unsigned) bytes/shorts/ints/longs or only parts of its - as some examples. So it does not matter whether the compared areas represent both unsigned or signed values. In your case you compare pointer values (unsigned int), no matter if the pointer is for (unsigend) int or something else. Both &u and &i point to 4 bytes in memory that are identical, I would say, the memory structure is the same.
But reading them with *u and *i will return a different value, only if the value was negative as signed int interpretation. So I would say the memory interpretation will be different.
But memcmp does not interpret anything.

**As far as I can tell from the standard, this is fine.** Yes, if the values are only positive (if interpreted as signed int) or smaller/equal than 0x7FFFU, if interpreted as unsigned int. Otherwise it is your responsibility with the side effects.

PS3: This problem can happen with pointer parameters in non-variadic and variadic methods - memcmp is a non-variadic function - see [definition of variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) (did not know it before your question).

Comment: That's why I say "Suppose I have an integer variable with non-negative value". If this assumption is true, I don't see a problem but I'm wondering whether this is guaranteed by the standard.